# Fadeout an Image then Changing the source and after changing fade in the Image again

Tags: jquery, css

i am working on a slider here.
What i am doing is on a button click say next, i am fading out an image and then dynamically changing the source and then fading in. Now i am not doing this with fadeOut() function, rather than i am doing this by adding a css class fadeOut where opacity is 0 then removing the class once the src is changed. How can i achive that? I also need some time before it fades in,
I tried addClass() and removeClass() method but they were so qucik that  the fade is not displayed.
please help.
thanks.

Here is the Code for the Next Button handler

```
 $('#nextHandler').click( function() {
        var nextListItem = ul.find('li.current').next();
        if ( nextListItem.length > 0 ) {
            ul.find('li.current').removeClass('current');
            nextListItem.addClass('current');
            var imagePath = ul.find('li.current').children('img').data("fullsrc");

            $('#fullImagePlaceholder').fadeOut(function () {
                $('#fullImagePlaceholder').attr('src', imagePath).fadeIn(500);
            }, 500);
        }
    });
});
```

Now i added the FadeOut function but it's till not working.

Comment: Can you please post the code you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted your actual code but I imagine you want something like this. When the **next** link/button is clicked, it will fade out your image, edit the `src` attribute to the new image and then fade in the image again.

```
var selectorForImg = 'img';
var newSrcLocation = 'img2.jpg';

$('#next').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('selectorForImg').fadeOut(function() {
        $('selectorForImg').attr('src', newSrcLocation).fadeIn(500);
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: I want to do this thing with a AddClass() method and not fadeOut() method where i add a Css class called fadeOut with opacity 0.

Comment: @MarcAndre "It's not working" is not really much to go on buddy. Also, why do you want to add a class with opacity 0? You don't want a transition or..?

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm not overly sure since I don't have any idea on the code you have so far but maybe something like this.

```
$(this).fadeOut("fast", function(){
        $(this).attr("background-image", "url([name of new image])").fadeIn("fast");
});
```

something like this, where this is the container of the image which is applied as a background image.

Comment: I don't think he is using `background-image`

Comment: You seem to have this covered in your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use css keyframe animations. ie.

```
@-webkit-keyframes animation-name {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes animation-name {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes animation-name {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes animation-name {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

div{
-webkit-animation: animation-name 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
-moz-animation: animation-name 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
-o-animation: animation-name 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
-ms-animation: animation-name 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
animation: animation-name 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
}
```

I posted an example here as well:
http://jsfiddle.net/guqv7/

Answer (score 0):

Whever you want something to be finished before the other thing begins, enclose it in a function();